# Can't do a fetch in node.js 19.7.0 module

Tags: node.js, networking, https, module, fetch

I have a simple .js file and inside that code:

```
fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(console.log);
```

I am trying to execute the code with node ./filename.js but get an error message:

```
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file and data are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'https:'
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at throwIfUnsupportedURLScheme (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:964:11)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1040:3)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:416:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME'
}

Node.js v19.7.0
```

when I use `node --experimental-network-imports ./filename.js` it works and I get the expected response... why is that? I thought fetch is supported natively by default in node and in version 19.7 this should not be experimental anymore or am I wrong?

Comment: Is that all your code? I ask because you can provoke the observed error with a statement like `import * from "https://dummyjson.com/products"`, and I doubt that the error comes from the `fetch`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen What exactly do you mean? I get the same error with your import statement..

Comment: Have you shared your entire code with us? Or is there an `import` statement in your code that causes the error?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen you were actually right .. the problem was another import:   `import { faker } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/@faker-js/faker';`  I installed it as a npm dependency instead from https, now I don't get the error anymore.. :)